# Tomcat 7 locks the jackrabbit repository

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7, jackrabbit

Hi I am trying to reach my repository via JNDI.

I recieve the following message when i try to connect:

> "The repository home C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.53-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\bin\myrepo > appears to be in use since the file named .lock is already locked by the current  process."

This code is runing on a web application, deployed on the same Tomcat.

```
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
Context environment = (Context) context.lookup("java:comp/env");        
Repository repository = (Repository) environment.lookup("jcr/repository");
```

Tomcat is locking "myrepo" when it starts and wont release it until I shuts it down.
Why is this happening?

Im running apache-tomcat-7.0.53-windows-x64 on Windows 7, using jackrabbit-webapp-2.6.5.war.

Edit May 10:
I have now tried to edit server.xml ann context.xml for my tomcat.

server.xml:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

      <Resource configFilePath="C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.53-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\bin\myrepo\repository.xml"
              factory="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.jndi.BindableRepositoryFactory"
              name="jcr/globalRepository" repHomeDir="C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.53-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\bin\myrepo"
              type="javax.jcr.Repository"
              auth="Container" />

  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

context.xml

```
<ResourceLink name="jcr/repository"
              global="jcr/globalRepository"
              type="javax.jcr.Repository"/>
```

The error is still the same.

Comment: Jackrabbit creates the lock so the repository can only one be accessed by one instance at a time.

Comment: So I can't access the repo from another web app? I tought that was the whole point with the jackrabbit-webapp. I want manage the repo using a web ui, adding new files etc.

Comment: As far as I know you should be able to access with multiple applications. From your message, sounds like you are trying to create multiple instances. Are you instantiating your repo in the tomcat server.xml? anywhere else as well, like standalone instances or web apps for example?

Comment: Yes, I created the repo using the jackrabbit-webapp, via the web UI. It created a "myrepo" folder where the repository.xml i located. I have made no changes to the server.xml.  

It is important that the jackrabbit-webapp can run at the same time, it enables WebDAV access to the repo.

Comment: I've now tried to config the repo JNDI on the server, see the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

There are a .lock file inside the repository folder. delete that file.